# High chart with strips on bar

Tags: jquery, asp.net, highcharts

I am using high chart to draw some graphical representations in my website.Used column graph.Column graph works fine.But now I need to show some strips in bar.How can i do it ?

```
 series: [
        {
                 name: 'Day',                
                 data: graphData,
                 color:'rgba(83, 223, 128, .6)',
                 zIndex: 0,                
                 type: 'column',
                 enableMouseTracking: false                
             }]
```

Please see the attached image.I want some thing like this.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use `pattern-fill` plugin to use some predefined patterns.

Add this to your HTML code:

```
<script src="https://highcharts.github.io/pattern-fill/pattern-fill-v2.js"></script>
```

Then, back to your chart:

```
series: [
    {
        name: 'Day',                
        data: graphData,
        color: 'url(#highcharts-default-pattern-1)',
        borderColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
        zIndex: 0,                
        type: 'column',
        enableMouseTracking: false                
    }
]
```

There are 10 predefined patterns: `highcharts-default-pattern-# (numbered 0-9)`

More information about making your own patterns in highchart [documentation](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/gradients-shadows-and-patterns).